# Ember createRecord / RESTAdapater without nesting

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a record with Ember and Node. Apparently, Ember likes to nest your object.

If I give it:

```
  this.store.createRecord('meal', {
    name: 'the name',
    meal_time: 'the time',
    tolerance: 'ouch'
  }).save();
```

Node gets this in `req.body`:

```
{ meal:
   { id: 'e5c90c23-1eb1-49e1-a3fa-865944b5eeea',
     name: 'the name',
     meal_time: 'the time',
     tolerance: 'ouch' } 
}
```

I'd rather modify the ember side than the node side.

Is there a way for `createRecord` to send the object without nesting it?

Comment: Thats how ember works ! It tries to save the model considering its a REST resource. Also from REST Api standpoint that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is overriding `Serializer.serializeIntoHash()`
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serializeIntoHash

```
serializeIntoHash(hash, type, snapshot, options) {
  Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(snapshot, options));
}
```

this code will remove that top level object from all outgoing models.

You can override it on your Application Serializer.. or any model-specific serializer you may have.

Answer (score 2):

You need to customize your serializer.

Create an application serializer like this: `ember g serializer application`.

Then edit it to use the basic [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html).

Then customize it by overriding its properties and methods to have it produce desired output.

The immediate method to customize is [normalizeCreateRecordResponse](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeCreateRecordResponse), but that's just the surface.

Ideally, you want consistent behavior for all kinds of operations, not only `createRecord`. Thus, you need to study how the serializer is organized. Read the [official guide to serializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/customizing-serializers/), intros to [JSONSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html) and [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html), look through RESTSerializer codebase.